# Getting remoteField to update another field

Tags: grails

I'm pretty new to Grails and trying out Ajax. In all of the examples I have looked at for remoteField, the result renders to a plain div area on the screen. I have this working, but I want the result from the controller to update the value in one of the gsp fields. When I set it up as shown below, the field element disappears and is replaced with just plain text. Is there a way to identify a specific field instead?

```
<div id="thisOne" class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: orderItemInstance, field: 'total', 'error')} required">
    <label for="total">
        <g:message code="orderItem.total.label" default="Total" />
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:field name="total" value="${fieldValue(bean: orderItemInstance, field: 'total')}" required=""/>
</div>

<div id="input" class="fieldcontain">
    <label for="input">
        Input field
    </label>
    <g:remoteField name="input" action="recalc" update="thisOne"/>
</div>
```

Comment: What field you want to update?

Comment: Thanks for all the input. All of the suggestions have merit, but the onSuccess answer was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `onSuccess` event of [remoteField](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteField.html), like

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: orderItemInstance, field: 'total', 'error')} required">
  <label for="total">
    <g:message code="orderItem.total.label" default="Total"/>
    <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
  </label>
  <g:field id="thisOne" type="text" name="total" value="${fieldValue(bean: orderItemInstance, field: 'total')}" required=""/>
</div>

<div id="input" class="fieldcontain">
  <label for="input">
    Input field
  </label>
  <g:remoteField name="input" action="test2" onSuccess="jQuery('#thisOne').val(data)"/>
</div>
```

Note:- thisOne is now id of the field

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="thisOne">
</div>
<div id="input" class="fieldcontain">
    <label for="input">
        Input field
    </label>
    <g:remoteField name="input" action="recalc" update="thisOne"/>
</div>
```

in _updateTotal.gsp

```
<div  class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: orderItemInstance, field: 'total', 'error')} required">
    <label for="total">
        <g:message code="orderItem.total.label" default="Total" />
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:field name="total" value="${fieldValue(bean: orderItemInstance, field: 'total')}" required=""/>
</div>
```

in action:

```
def recalc(){
.....
render(template:"updateTotal",....)
}
```

When using ajax, we update div that time the previous value will be disappear.So u put the content as template that will be content of the div.

so i put the total field in one template. In controller action that called in remote field will render the template. try like this.